# Divide png image to button with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this png image:

[image]

How can I divide this image on (next button) (previous button) with the red effect on hover ?

Can I do this only with CSS or I need Jquery too ? I never did that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any examples to know about css sprites?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144908/any-examples-to-know-about-css-sprites)

Comment: if you wanna use css only then create a css sprite, you can use an online css sprite generator. Then you can use the the .png image generated and just adjust the background-position to get which button you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this image called sprite


<a class="next-btn">
</div>
<a class="prev-btn">
</div>

.next-btn
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000000 url(images/G980P.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.prev-btn
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000000 url(images/G980P.png) -25px 0 no-repeat;
}
.next-btn:hover
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000000 url(images/G980P.png) 0 -25px no-repeat;
}
.prev-btn:hover
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #000000 url(images/G980P.png) -25px -25px no-repeat;
}

refer this page for how to work sprite background

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with pure css. All you need to do is shift the background position on hover.

```
#LeftArrow {
             width:25px;height:25px;
             background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G980P.png);
             background-position: 0 0;}

#LeftArrow:hover {
             background-position: 0 -25px;}
```

I have created a demo on Codepen for you to check out how it's done.
http://codepen.io/The_Animator/pen/vEzJee